# add class to previous step in checkout page

Tags: magento2.3, onestepcheckout

In checkout page steps, I need to add a class to the previous step that is done to have three colors: red for active, black for next, and green for the previous step

Comment: inspect the item you want to add class and grep it in app folder or vendor folder with command
grep -rl "item unique class or id" app/
or
grep -rl "item unique class or id" app/
this will give you the file then override it if it in in vendor

Answer (score 1):

You already have 2 status classes associated with the "**.opc-progress-bar-item**" class:

- "**_active**" => red for you
- "**_complete**" when the step is passed => green for you

If needed, see the following file to add your own classes:

```
httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/progress-bar.html
```

Answer (score 0):

adding below CSS on the checkout page should work.
You may need to change the class i.e. `opc-progress-bar` according to the theme.

```
    ul.opc-progress-bar li.opc-progress-bar-item > span {
        color: black;
    }

    ul.opc-progress-bar-item > span:before, .opc-progress-bar-item > span:after {
        border-color: black;
    }

    ul.opc-progress-bar li.opc-progress-bar-item._complete > span {
        color: green;
    }

    ul.opc-progress-bar li.opc-progress-bar-item._complete:before,
    ul.opc-progress-bar li.opc-progress-bar-item._complete > span:before {
        background: green;
        border-color: green;
    }

    ul.opc-progress-bar li.opc-progress-bar-item._active > span {
        color: red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in magento 2.4.6 and also adds checkout step classes on page load (and change checkout step event).
Adjust the class names to your need.

Override progress-bar.js in you custom active theme(Path given below):

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/progress-bar.js

Add below code right after `stepNavigator.handleHash();` (but still inside the initialize: function).

Add class on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if (location.hash === '#shipping') {
    $(document.body)
        .removeClass('payment-step')
        .addClass('shipping-step');
}

if (location.hash === '#payment') {
    $(document.body)
        .removeClass('shipping-step')
        .addClass('payment-step');
}
});
```

Add class on change checkout step event:

```
window.onhashchange = function(){

if (location.hash === '#shipping') {
    $(document.body)
        .removeClass('payment-step')
        .addClass('shipping-step');
}

if (location.hash === '#payment') {
    $(document.body)
        .removeClass('shipping-step')
        .addClass('payment-step');
}
};
```